# Jenkins stop build if no commit since last succeed build

Tags: svn, jenkins, groovy, build

I want to schedule a jenkins build every day, but only if there was a commit.
To do so, I tried using groovy jenkins plugin with a pre-build script.
 But it didn't worked, my condition is wrong I think.

Here is what I have:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def thisBuild = thr?.executable

def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def testSuite = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("TEST_SUITE")

def item = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("$testSuite")
def jobBuild = item.getLastSuccessfulBuild()

// stop the current build only if the last succeed revesion is inferior
// of current svn_revision
if (jobBuild.getNumber() < svn_revision){
    thisBuild.setResult(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
    thisBuild.executor.interrupt(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the poll scm options in job setting. You can pass the cron like expression to tell Jenkins how often it should pull the given scm repository. it will only trigger the job if there will be new change in repository.